# PC shuts down when installing ubuntu?

Tags: 11.04, live-usb, installation

I'm now using ubuntu from USB, and I'd like to install ubuntu on my hard disk.

I tried the option of removing Vista while installing ubuntu.

However, near the end of the installation process (presumably the end because I can see some slideshows on how to start using ubuntu), the screen suddenly goes to black with white words running around on it. Soon the computer shuts down.

After that, restarting leads to a black screen with only a small white cursor on the top left corner. The cursor keeps blinking and nothing happens.

I found that I can alternatively choose to boot with USB by hitting `F12` just when the computer starts. So I tried to reinstall ubuntu by running ubuntu on USB. One of the options of installation is to `update ubuntu 11.04 to ubuntu 11.04`, so it seems the ubuntu is already installed somehow.

Anyways, I tried both `update` and `delete and install` option but the same thing happens as the 1st time (sometimes before reaching the end), while I still cannot start my PC as ubuntu (without USB).

How may I install ubuntu properly?

Comment: Ensure you REMOVE the USB before the restart - it's likely you are just booting into the live USB each time on a restart

Comment: Actually, it was not USB.
I tried reinstalling now and it led to the `continue using` or `reboot`, which never happened before.
Maybe something is wrong with my PC. But I'm glad it worked. Thanks anyway for the help.

Comment: For those who have the same problem, try removing the bottom cover of your laptop. I had the same problem when I updated from 11.04 to 11.10, and it worked. It doesn't solve the cause of overheating though.

Answer (score 1):

I have had almost the same problem when installing Ubuntu 11.10 on my laptop.  For some reason I do not get the usual installation graphical interface, however I get to install Ubuntu.  But after installation is complete, I reboot the machine remove the pendrive and Ubuntu starts loading but then it stops, a cursor appears on the upper left corner of the screen and nothing else happens... ever again!!.

I thought it may be an issue of the pendrive, since the installation interface was not as expected for 11.10, so I burn a Live CD and rebooted from it.  So far the installation process has no problems and its graphical interface is working fine.  I will report back after installation is completed.  So far it seems that the problem was the USB installer being faulty.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add nomodeset to your kernel option at boot... if it work please read:

http://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2010/05/06/ubuntu-10-04-lucid-blank-screen-at-startup-workaround/

to made this option as permanent...

Comment: I tried the similar [thing](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/06/linux-kernel-power-issue-fix.html) after installing Ubuntu, and my desktop went blank. Although I could use the terminal with `Ctrl+Alt+T` and remove the code from the file (and `sudo update-grub` & restart), it didn't fix the blank desktop. So I had to reinstall Ubuntu.